# Looking for the "Hello World" of ctypes unicode processing (including both Python and C code)

Tags: python, c, ctypes

Can someone show me a really simple Python ctypes example involving Unicode strings **including the C code?**

Say, a way to take a Python Unicode string and pass it to a C function which catenates it with itself and returns that to Python, which prints it.

Answer (score 6):

This program uses `ctypes` to call [`wcsncat`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Copying-and-Concatenation.html#index-wcsncat-511) from Python. It concatenates `a` and `b` into a buffer that is not quite long enough for `a + b + (null terminator)` to demonstrate the safer `n` version of concatenation.

You must pass `create_unicode_buffer()` instead of passing a regular immutable `u"unicode string"` for non-const `wchar_t*` parameters, otherwise you will probably get a segmentation fault.

If the function you need to talk to returns UCS-2 and `sizeof(wchar_t) == 4` then you will not be able to use `unicode_buffer()` because it converts between `wchar_t` to Python's internal Unicode representation. In that case you might be able to use some combination of `result.create_string_buffer()` and `result.decode('UCS2')` or just create an array of `c_short` and `u''.join(unichr(c) for c in buffer)`. I had to do that to debug an ODBC driver.

example.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from ctypes import *
example = cdll.LoadLibrary(".libs/libexample.so")
example.its_an_example.restype = c_wchar_p
example.its_an_example.argtypes = (c_wchar_p, c_wchar_p, c_uint)
buf = create_unicode_buffer(19) # writable, unlike u"example".
buf[0] = u"\u0000"
a = u"あがぃいぅ ☃ "
b = u"個人 相命理 網上聯盟"
print example.its_an_example(buf, a, len(buf) - len(buf.value) - 1)
print example.its_an_example(buf, b, len(buf) - len(buf.value) - 1)
print buf.value # you may have to .encode("utf-8") before printing
sys.stdout.write(buf.value.encode("utf-8") + "\n")
```

example.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <wchar.h>

wchar_t *its_an_example(wchar_t *dest, const wchar_t *src, size_t n) {
    return wcsncat(dest, src, n);
}
```

Makefile: (ensure the indentation is one tab character, not spaces):

```
all:
    libtool --mode=compile gcc -g -O -c example.c
    libtool --mode=link gcc -g -O -o libexample.la example.lo \
            -rpath /usr/local/lib
```

Comment: great answer! This is the best "getting started" example on ctypes I've ever found! Thanks a lot! Note that I had to change the load to cdll.LoadLibrary("./.libs/libexample.so.0") but everybody should be able to fix similar details on his/her machine

Answer (score -1):

Untested, but I think this should work.

```
s = "inputstring"
mydll.my_c_fcn.restype = c_char_p
result = mydll.my_c_fcn(s)
print result
```

As for memory management, my understanding is that your c code needs to manage the memory it creates.  That is, it should not free the input string, but eventually needs to free the return string.

Comment: This answer includes ctypes and processing, but omits the unicode!

Comment: He posted that request well after I wrote this code.  A bit harsh to downvote 3 months after the question and it's modification.  (There should be a rule against this: the fact that I answer the question shouldn't guarantee a perpetual commitment from me to answer whatever question the OP eventually morphs it into.)

Comment: Sorry for the harshness. I'd change my vote but it won't let me.

Answer (score -1):

```
from ctypes import *

buffer = create_string_buffer(128)
cdll.msvcrt.strcat(buffer, "blah")
print buffer.value
```

> Note: I understand that the Python code is easy, but what I'm struggling with is the C code. Does it need to free its input string? Will its output string get freed by Python on its behalf?

No, you need to manually free the buffer yourself. What people normally do is copy the python string immediately from buffer.value, and then free the buffer.

> Can you post the C code? – mike 2 hours ago

```
#include <string.h>

char* mystrcat(char* buffer) {
    strcat(buffer, "blah");
    return buffer;
}
```